# Random fire *of* a likely enemy location, in order to disrupt his activities - is "fire of" OK here?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, prepositions

In the quiz sentence "*Random *fire* *of* a likely enemy location, in order to disrupt his activities*" can we use the word combination ***fire of***?

To me it sounds incorrect, I would rather write *fire at* or *fire on* instead.

So, what is the right variant, or are they all correct?

Comment: Hi - this sort of question is off-topic here because you're not actually asking a specific question about English, you're just asking for some text to be *checked*. You already seem to recognise that it is incorrect.

Comment: Please don't cross-post to multiple SE sites. Pick one & stick to it, or flag for migration. 
[Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/) - https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/611848/random-fire-of-a-likely-enemy-location-in-order-to-disrupt-his-activities-is

Comment: ***fire of*** isn't a valid verb+preposition here. The "verb" needs to be a ***gerund/continuous*** form: *Random **firing on/at** a likely enemy location...* Note that preposition ***on*** is fine with a different verb: *Random **shelling/bombing of** a likely enemy location...*

Answer (score 0):

The "fire of an enemy" means the firing *done by* the enemy.

> The man next to me was killed by the fire of an enemy sniper.

If you mean fire targetting an enemy you call it "fire at" or "fire on".

> We fired at the enemy sniper in order to disrupt his aim.